# how to create custom gauges with Spring Boot and Micrometer?

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer

I wrote a Spring Boot app and I'd like to expose custom metrics to Prometheus with [Micrometer](http://micrometer.io/). Here's a code snippet where I'm incrementing a counter (which works) and attempts to set a couple of gauges (which doesn't work):

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/2 * * * * *") // run every 2 seconds
private void logTemperature() throws UnknownHostException {

    // get measurement
    SensorReader sensorReader = new SensorReader();
    SensorReading sensorReading = sensorReader.getSensorReading();

    Metrics.counter("measurements").increment();
    Metrics.gauge("fahrenheit", sensorReading.getFahrenheit());
    Metrics.gauge("humidity", sensorReading.getHumidity());

    // do stuff with measurement
    // ...

}
```

The complete source code is here: https://github.com/alexwoolford/htu21d_logger/tree/master/htu21d-logger-spring

The `fahrenheit` field in the `sensorReading` object is a `float`. The gauges exist in the output, however the value is `NaN` (i.e. not a number):

```
# HELP measurements_total  
# TYPE measurements_total counter
measurements_total 82.0
...
# HELP humidity  
# TYPE humidity gauge
humidity NaN
...
# HELP fahrenheit  
# TYPE fahrenheit gauge
fahrenheit NaN
...
```

I've seen similar posts, e.g. [Micrometer/Prometheus How do I keep a gauge value from becoming NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879488/micrometer-prometheus-how-do-i-keep-a-gauge-value-from-becoming-nan) and [Micrometer - Prometheus Gauge displays NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821924/micrometer-prometheus-gauge-displays-nan), but I can't figure out what, specifically, I need to do from those answers.

I also tried creating a variable and updating that with a lambda, e.g.

```
Metrics.gauge("humidity", humidity, humidity -> sensorReading.getHumidity());
```

... and the guage disappeared altogether (not even an `NaN`).

This question is slightly different from the others since I'm not using a cache and I'm attempting to use the global registry which, presumably, is the simplest option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The objects that you are using are getting garbage collected since noting is holding onto a reference of those values. Gauges use weak references by default.

If you set it to use strong references it should avoid the `NaN`s. Unfortunately the global registry helpers don't expose the gauge builder so you'll need to create the gauge a little differently.

```
Gauge.builder("humidity", humidity, humidity -> sensorReading.getHumidity()).strongReference(true).register(Metrics.globalRegistry);
```

As a side note I would recommend moving away from the `@Scheduled` approach unless the sensor reading is inherently slow. If the `SensorReader` is thread safe, you could remove the `@Scheduled` and use the `SensorReader` directly:

```
SensorReader sensorReader = new SensorReader();

Gauge.builder("humidity", sensorReader, sensorReader -> 
  sensorReader.getSensorReading().getHumidity())
  .strongReference(true)
  .register(Metrics.globalRegistry);
Gauge.builder("fahrenheit", sensorReader, sensorReader -> 
  sensorReader.getSensorReading().getFahrenheit())
  .strongReference(true)
  .register(Metrics.globalRegistry);
```

That way you'll only be looking up the sensor reading are the rate that Prometheus is scraping the metrics.

Comment: That's awesome, @checketts. Thank you so much.